# Custom Security for API access from server to mobile application

Tags: php, android, security

i am not the best at security but need a custom way to securely store personal identifiable information like name, address etc - Can i please have some feedback on this custom code, from my perspective it looks okay but with security not being my strong point i don't trust myself.

The data is passed from my application over HTTPS in the header along with a custom auth code which is made up from the users unique ID, fcm ID, package name and the epoch date they obtained the auth code.

This is sent to the server on every request and decrypted to make sure that we have the correct user - the server won't provide any details back to the unless the epoch date matches (this is stored in the database on the auth creation)

Here is the encrypt / decrypt function

```
function encrypt($string, $public_key = "public key", $action = "e") {
     $secret_key = "secret key";
     $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
     $key = hash( 'sha256', $public_key );
     $secret = substr( hash( 'sha256', $secret_key), 0, 16 );

     if( $action == 'e' ) {
          $output = base64_encode( openssl_encrypt( $string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $secret) );
     } else if ( $action == 'd') {
          $output = openssl_decrypt( base64_decode( $string ), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $secret);
     }
     if (empty($output)) {
          denyAccess();
     }
     return $output;
}
```

the data stored in the database uses the same function but with different keys so the data is encrypted twice.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I couldn't answer your question, too much code is missing for my taste, but I do notice two things: 1. The variable `$secret_key` is never used, and the variable `$secret_iv` is never defined. Is that a mistake? 2. Your function encrypts and decrypts, but is simply called `encrypt()`. That is _very_ confusing. This should be split into 2 functions, or be a class. A tip: Give us more code to review, that way you will get a better review. There simply isn't much to review here.

Comment: Also: `$output` will probably never be empty. Unless, of course, you provide an invalid `$action`. However, I think you want to respond to the input `$string` of this function, not the output.

Comment: `else` is more appropriate than `if (empty($output)) {`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes sorry i changed the variable names when copying on here for easier readability the secret_iv is the secret_key

Comment: Are we really only to review this solitary function? Are we right to assume that `denyAccess();` kills everything (the function `encrypt()` never gets a chance to return)?  How are `encrypt()` calls performed? We'd like to see more code.